# How to pass from kotlin array of data class to an array of C struct with JNI?

Tags: android, c, kotlin, java-native-interface

I have to create an Android library using C code (which is just a Kotlin and JNI wrapper around three C functions). But as I'm completely new to JNI, I'm struggling with one thing: How do you back and forth between C struct and Kotlin data class with JNI? Specifically when working with arrays

Here is the small C library I need to work with:

```c
typedef struct
{
    double x, y, z;
}
POINT3DZ;

char *encode_to_char(const POINT3DZ *p, int length); //POINT3DZ *p is a pointer to an array
POINT3DZ *get_point(const POINT3DZ *p, int length, int n); //POINT3DZ *p is a pointer to an array
POINT3DZ *decode_char(const char *base64Char, int *size);
```

Here is my current JNI wrapper for the first two methods:

```c
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_package_MyClass_encode(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject object,
        jobjectArray point3dz,
        int length) {

    char *twkbChar = (char *)encode_to_char((POINT3DZ const *)point3dz,length);
    jstring twkb = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, (const char *)twkbChar);
    return twkb;
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_package_MyClass_getPoint(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject object,
        jobjectArray point3dz,
        int length,
        int n) {
    char *twkbChar = (char *)get_point((POINT3DZ const *)point3dz,length, n);
    jstring twkb = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, (const char *)twkbChar);
    return twkb;
}
```

And here is my Kotlin implementation:

```kotlin
class MyClass {
   
    external fun encode(pointT3DZ: Array<POINT3DZ>, length: Int): String
    external fun getPoint(pointT3DZ: POINT3DZ, size: Int, n: Int): POINT3DZ
    external fun decode(myString: String, size: Int): POINT3DZ
    
    companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("my-lib")
        }
    }
}

data class POINT3DZ(
    val x: Double,
    val y: Double,
    val z: Double,
)
```

Running my unit test, my JNI implementation are wrong. It seems be an issue with handling Kotlin Data class to C Struct and same with a Kotlin Array class to an Array of struct. Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Things will not be as simple as you seem to have hoped. First you'll have to use `FindClass` and `GetFieldID` to get the necessary information about the Kotlin `POINT3DZ` class. Then you'll have to use `GetArrayLength` and `GetObjectArrayElement` to extract each Kotlin `POINT3DZ` instance from the `jobjectArray`, and finally `GetDoubleField` to extract the `x`, `y` and `z` members, from which you can create a C `POINT3DZ` struct.

Comment: See [the JNI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) for a list of available functions and descriptions of what they do.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to check the documentation!